# FacetAPI graphs not working

Tags: search

I have been trying to use FacetAPI graphs for my site but no luck yet . 
after doing all the configuration set up facetapi - > selecting  'Graph Combo' in filter option and display configuration. when I execute the search , the search gives blank page in chrome , the same operation done in IE gives error 500 . 
while doing  the configurations setup I noticed In Facet Combo the Y FACET scroll has blank. I dont know if it can be cause of problem .
Any pointers in fixing this is highly appreciated 
Regards 
Sakar

Comment: Your server error log should contain more details about what's going wrong, could you post any related error messages from there?

Answer (score 0):

FacetAPI graph doesnt work with solrsearch it seems , I installed search api and was able to get all the options and fixed the problem .